# How to get Item Position in EpoxyModelWithHolder?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, epoxy

I'm trying to add a RecyclerView to my app using Epoxy Library
I need to get position of the item in `bind` method in `EpoxyModelWithHolder` but I don't know how to do that.

I couldn't find any function to get the position of holder/item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to have an Integer EpoxyAttribute in your model and in your controller set it to id from buildItemModel method.

In your model:

```
@EpoxyAttribute
Integer position;
```

In controller:

```
public EpoxyModel<?> buildItemModel(int i, yourmodel) {

return model()_.id(i).position(i);

}
```